# R plotly: Customize x-axis values in box plot

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data frame with 3 variables and 260 rows. (Sample below)

```
HouseID<-c(1:10)
Town<-c("D","A","B","C","A","B","C","C","C","A")
Occupants<-c(5,3,2,4,5,2,3,8,1,3)
df<-data.frame(HouseID,Town,Occupants)

HouseID Town Occupants
1       D     5
2       A     3
3       B     2
4       C     4
5       A     5
6       B     2
7       C     3
8       C     8
9       C     1
10      A     3
```

I want to create a box plot for the distribution of Occupants with the order of x-axis based on the descending order of frequencies of Towns

```
Town Freq
A    3
B    2
C    4
D    1
```

(Shown a sample image)

[image: Sample Boxplot]

I tried sorting the data frame, but still, the box plot x-axis is displayed based on alphabetical order by default. Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to use `factor` to reorder levels of `df$Town` according to their count `summary(df$Town)`:

```
df$Town <- factor(df$Town, levels(df$Town)[order(summary(df$Town),decreasing = TRUE)])
plot_ly(df, x=~Town, y=~Occupants, type="box")
```

[image]

Comment: @HubertL- Thanks. I did not think of putting a function of summary inside the order function. This works!